# Vector graphics used for google map marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to use vector graphics to be google maps marker? I know that google maps takes a bitmap for a marker, but I have a vector graphics (coming from server) and I am not sure how to display that as marker?

Thank you

Comment: Who ever downvoted, maybe you could spare spending 4 seconds saying why. It is totally valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, if you are able to render your vector image as a Drawable, you can use it as a map marker. Vector drawables on Android are complicated but maybe you already solved that problem.

You need to programmatically create a writable Bitmap with the desired size (specify your constant size in dips to adjust it to the screen density), create a Canvas based on that Bitmap, set the bounds on your Drawable then draw it on the Canvas. Your Bitmap will then contain the rendering of your Drawable and you can create a Marker from it.

Comment: So thats my problem then, how do I get this vector to become drawable? :) I am missing the link between vector graphics and a graphics that android undertands

Comment: @Snake Android understands VectorDrawables (a **subset** of SVG files) only since Lollipop. Alternatively (and better suited, at the moment), you can use a free SVG parsing library, which will return a drawable from a standard SVG file.

Comment: No SVG parsing library is perfect and you should really target the lowest possible SVG profile to maximize compatibility: SVG Tiny is preferred, or SVG Basic. You can also get VectorDrawable compatibility on older versions using the "MrVector" library or soon using the support library. I don't know which format your server accepts or returns but your best option is really to let your server perform the transformation to Bitmap.

Comment: It surely won't accept  Android's **proprietary** `VectorDrawable`. AndroidSvg or SvgAndoid are valid alternatives for handling `SVG` **standard** format.

Answer (score 0):

> but I have a vector graphics file and I am not sure how to achieve that?

Open it in your vector drawing app and export as bitmap (PNG) to use on Android. This is the less painful way than anything else.

Comment: I wish it was that :). The problem is that it coming from server so as it gets uploaded by users. I will clarify the question as the "file maybe misleadling"

Comment: then perhaps your server shall render it into bitmap? Using vectors on Android is rather P.I.T.A. as most system methods expects bitmaps. Still you can create own, custom View and render vector graphics (or maybe there's such 3rd party component already - you need to search a bit)

Comment: The whole reason why I want o use vector graphics so that  I save on the size needs to be downloaded. It will be animation which involves multiple images (sprite sheet kind of thing). If I use images from the server then downloading it will be problem as there will be alot of them. Using vector graphics  is  "supposdly" to be math that instructs the system how to  draw them so it it is supposed to be much less size

Comment: In practice you won't gain much bandwidth between a "vector image" and a PNG or a WebP file, unless the displayed image is very, very big. But you will lose a lot of CPU power since decoding complex vector images is extremely costly on a mobile device. Also, I'm not aware of any vector format which supports animations except for AnimatedVectorDrawable which is only supported in Android Lollipop and requires a very strict format.

Comment: @BladeCoder FYI: you can have animations in SVG.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sorry, I meant: I'm not aware of any animated SVG format working on Android except for AnimatedVectorDrawable.